# Change page before AJAX async request ends

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

**View**

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    $('#result').html("Processing...");
    $.ajax({
       url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Json")',
       async: true,
       dataType: "json",
       type: "GET",
       success: function (data) {
           $('#result').html(data);
       },
    });
    return false;
});
```

**Controller**

```
public class JsonController : AsyncController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetData()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/myservice.svc/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("GetData");
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JSONResponse>();
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
class JSONResponse{ 
    public int Value { get; set; } 
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I'm calling an wcf restful service asynchronously from an asp.net mvc application and displaying the result in a div.
When I click the button and the service starts processing and I try to change page meanwhile, I can't... and the page only changes after I get the result from the service.

How can I make it so I can keep changing while the service is executing and when is finished I just display the data in the div?

EDIT: Changing page meaning render different partial views below the div.

Answer (score 1):

As I describe on my blog, [`async` doesn't change the HTTP protocol](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-doesnt-change-http-protocol.html).

You'll need to use a technology designed for this, such as SignalR.